# Unity load texture in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to load textures to my app from specific directory. For instance, there is a jpg file on my desktop (or anywhere else, but locally on HDD) and I want it to be a texture for some plane on scene. Now in my build I can choose a file from open dialog. After choosing the texture - my code copies it to 
Application.persistentDataPath. Then I want to load it to into app and convert it to Texture - and this is where the troubles started because I don't know how to convert file to Texture. Have anyone tried this before with Unity? Any idea how to approach this?